# Recursion: pick 8 balls from a bag. Problem: how to avoid same answers?

Tags: c, recursion

I am stuck into a recursion problem. 
Question: There are 3 red balls, 3 white balls and 6 black balls in a bag. Need to take 8 balls from the bag. How many combinations are there and what are they?

I have implemented the question in C. But the problem is i do not know how to get rid of exact same solutions from my answers. The actual answer is 13 combinations, which i have verified using "uniq" operator of UNIX. However i would like to get some help on how to remove same combination from my program.

Much appreciate !!! Thank you.

```
// 3R 3W 6B, pick 8, how many possible combination

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void func(int r, int w, int b, int total);


int main(void){
    printf("The result is\n");
    func(3, 3, 6, 0);
    return 0;
}


void func(int r, int w, int b, int total){
    if (r < 0 || w < 0 || b < 0){
        return;
    }
    else if (total >= 8){
        printf("R = %d, W = %d, B = %d\n", 3-r, 3-w, 6-b);
        return;
    }
    else{
        func(r-1, w, b, total+1);
        func(r, w-1, b, total+1);
        func(r, w, b-1, total+1);

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By taking one ball at a time from each colour, you reach the same answer on different paths. For example taking a red, then a white ball will lead to the same count as taking a white, then a red ball. In your code, each level of recursion corresponds to an individual ball, which is a good approach if the order of balls is important.

You can order the taking differently:

- consider all possibilities to take red balls (0, 1, 2,or 3)

  - consider all ways to take white balls (0 to 3 again)

    - consider all ways to take black balls (0 to 6)

      - if we have 8 balls, print the solution

(This solution is not optimal: It will consider all possibilities in a brute-froce-ish way. It can be optimized by not reducing the possibilities depending on how many balls have already been taken. The key point here is to see that reordering your recursion solves the problem.)

You can hard-code this into your program, but let's consider a more general solution, where you specify the available number of balls of each colour n an array and the total amount.

This solution is recursive, too, but here each level of recursion corresponds to the colour of a ball:

```
int take(int *ball,     // array of available balls of each colour
         int *taken,    // record of balls taken from each colour
         int n,         // size of ball and taken arrays
         int i,         // currently considered colour
         int total)     // balls taken, counting down from intended number
{
    int res = 0;
    int j;

    if (i < n) {
        // consider nexz colour

        for (j = 0; j < ball[i] + 1; j++) {
            taken[i] = j;

            res += take(ball, taken, n, i + 1, total - j);
        }
    } else {
        // all colours have been considered

        if (total == 0) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (j) printf(", ");
                printf("%d", taken[j]);
            }

            puts("");

            res = 1;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

For your test case, call it like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int ball[] = {3, 3, 6};     // red, white and black balls
    int taken[3];               // will be filled in by "take"

    int res = take(ball, taken, 3, 0, 8);

    printf("(%d possibilities)\n", res);

    return 0;
}
```